# Problem with pom.xml when I create a new java project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

[image]

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT failed to transfer from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): repo.spring.io and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POMJava(0)

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
 

com.test
test
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
test
 project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: The spring repositories for milestones are only available public. The snapshot repos are not anymore (for a longer time)..If you like to consume milestone releases only configure them ...Is there a reason to really need to use SNAPSHOT versions? Use the released versions like spring boot 2.5.5 ... ?

Comment: Hi, as @khmarbaise wrote, why you need a SNAPSHOT version? Switch to a stable one like `2.5.5`